# How read a raster [Tiff] file to get the correct values for every band?

Tags: raster, gdal, geotiff-tiff, c++, rgb

I am trying to read a raster tiff [RGBA] file with GDAL in [C++], I can load the file, get  the number of channels, the size of the bands and the metadata, but when I try to extract the Band [R, G or B] I get the images in gray scale but all of them has the same values; so when I try to merge them with opencv I get a Gray image and not the RGB, The code that I use to do this process is below... Could you give me an idea of what I am doing wrong?

I read the following answers and the GDAL doc but dont get a good result... 
Link 1: [Correct way to extract pixel data using GDAL. Current method gives repeated but changing value.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109058/correct-way-to-extract-pixel-data-using-gdal-current-method-gives-repeated-but)

Link 2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33807705/create-an-rbg-color-qimage-from-a-gdaldataset?fbclid=IwAR1wIsteSrEyfZGGQW9s9gK4GyIYi6AIvFR_47FsDKbgfSEv5hrhsznT1ss  [I use this code and also try the GDALRASTERIO method]

Code:

```
    // Register all Drivers
    GDALAllRegister(); 
    // Load the raster
    GDALDataset *dataset = (GDALDataset *) GDALOpen(path, GA_ReadOnly);
    // Get some features of the raster
    int raster_cols = dataset->GetRasterXSize(),
            raster_rows = dataset->GetRasterYSize(),
            raster_channels = dataset->GetRasterCount();
    // keep data - Channels and Type of the image
   std::vector<std::string> raster_bandName(raster_channels),
                            raster_BandType(raster_channels); 
   std::vector<cv::Mat> Mybands(raster_channels, cv::Mat( raster_rows, raster_cols, CV_8UC1 )); // Byte[Raster] -- 8U [OpenCV]
   cv::Mat img;
    // Walk over the bands ---
    for(int i = 1; i < raster_channels; i++)
    {
        // Get the data of the available bands 
        GDALRasterBand *poBand = dataset->GetRasterBand(i);
        raster_BandType[i-1] = GDALGetDataTypeName(poBand->GetRasterDataType());
        // Get some descriptor of the band that was loaded 
        raster_bandName[i-1] = GDALGetColorInterpretationName(poBand->GetColorInterpretation());

        std::string ban = raster_bandName[i-1];

        poBand->RasterIO(   GF_Read, 0, 0, raster_cols, raster_rows, 
                            Mybands[i-1].data, raster_cols, raster_rows, 
                            GDT_Byte, 0, 0 ); // Write the Image data in the OpenCV var


        std::cout<<raster_BandType[i-1]<<" "<<raster_bandName[i-1]<<std::endl;

    }

    cv::merge(Mybands,  img );
```

**Update:** The following code works for me, I don't see a real difference but It returns the desired image.....

```
GDALAllRegister();
GDALDataset *dataset = (GDALDataset *) GDALOpen(path, GA_ReadOnly);
int raster_cols = dataset->GetRasterXSize(),
                  raster_rows = dataset->GetRasterYSize(),
                  raster_channels = dataset->GetRasterCount();

    for(int i = 1; i < raster_channels; i++)
    {
        // Save the channel in var not in the vector of Mat
        cv::Mat bckVar(raster_rows, raster_cols, CV_8UC1  );

        GDALRasterBand *poBand = dataset->GetRasterBand(i);

        poBand->RasterIO(   GF_Read, 0, 0, raster_cols, raster_rows, 
                            bckBar.data, raster_cols, raster_rows, 
                            poBand->GetRasterDataType(), 0, 0 );
        // Image is a std::vector<cv::Mat> image;
        image.push_back( bckBar.clone() );
        // Clean mm
        bckBar.release();
    }

    cv::merge( image, usrImage2w );// RGB ok
```

Comment: How is this question different than the one in the first link you provided?

Comment: Hello @Aaron !!  You are right, my question takes the same problem, but when I try the solution that they propose I get the same results.. I was asking for another advice to try to solve my error..  I tried the same approach with Python and it works!.... regards